# Expressing covariance and contravariance in Java vs Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

In Kotlin I can declare a type with a covariant type as such.

```
class Request<out T> { }
```

And a contravariant type as following

```
class Request<in T> { }
```

I'm struggling to determine how this can be achieved with Java. In particular more advanced generics in Kotlin like the following.

```
interface RequestHandler<in TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest: Request<TResponse> { }
```

What is the the Java equivalent?

Comment: Java doesn't have declaration site variance.